# how to get a kernel global variable address from userspace

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

I defined a global variable such as "int g_abc" in kernel module.
Now i want to get the g_abc address from my user space process.
Then open "/dev/kmem" and use the "mmap" function to map the variable into my process . I have known i can write such as "ioctl" get the address,but I hope it can  use some function to get address directly. only need to pass the global variable name into the function.who know the function?

Comment: File `/proc/kallsyms` contains addresses for all kernel symbols. You may `grep` this file for the name of your variable.

Comment: is there any c function to get the address？

Comment: There is no ready C function for doing this.